# Spring Security で ROLE の判断が上手くいかない

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-security

#### 実現したいこと

Spring Bootを使用し、予約サイトを作っています。
現在Spring Security用のDialectを使用し、sec:authorizeでRoleがADMINまたはログインユーザーIDと予約者のユーザーIDが一致した場合に予約取り消しフォームを表示する機能を実装中です。

#### 発生している問題

ログインユーザーのRoleがADMINでも、予約取り消しフォームが表示されない。一方で、ログインユーザーIDと予約者のユーザーIDが一致した場合は予約取り消しフォームは表示されています。デバックしたところ、RoleにはきちんとADMINがセットされています。エラーメッセージなどは出ていません。

#### 試したこと

色々と調べてみたところ自分と同じような問題をかかえている方がおり、その人はhasRoleではなくhasAuthorityを使用すると上手く出来たそうです。しかし、自分も試してみましたが上手くいきませんでした。試しにhasRoleにUSERを入れてみましたが、それも上手くいきませんでした。
その後も調べていましたが、解決に至らずここで質問をさせて頂いています。よろしくお願いします。

---

#### ソースコード

reserveForm.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-spring-security5">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title
    th:text="|${#temporals.format(date, 'yyyy/M/d')}の${room.roomName}|"></title>
</head>
<body th:with="user=${#authentication.principal.user}">

    <div>
        <a th:href="@{'/rooms/' + ${date}}">会議室へ</a>
    </div>

    <!-- 予約が出来なかった場合の処理 -->
    <p style="color: red" th:if="${error != null}" th:text="${error}"></p>

    <form th:object="${reservationForm}"
        th:action="@{'/reservations/' + ${date} + '/' + ${roomId}}"
        method="post">

        会議室: <span th:text="${room.roomName}"></span> <br />
        予約者名: <span th:text="${user.lastName + '' + user.firstName}"></span> <br />
        日付: <span th:text="${#temporals.format(date, 'yyyy/M/d')}"></span> <br />
        時間帯:<select th:field="*{startTime}">
                    <option th:each="time : ${timeList}" th:text="${time}" th:value="${time}"></option>
               </select> <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('startTime')}"
            th:errors="*{startTime}" style="color: red">error!</span>
            <select th:field="*{endTime}">
                <option th:each="time : ${timeList}" th:text="${time}"
                    th:value="${time}"></option>
                <option th:each="time : ${timeList}" th:text="${time}"
                    th:value="${time}"></option>
            </select> <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('endTime')}" th:errors="*{endTime}"
            style="color: red">error!</span> <br />
        <button>予約</button>
    </form>

    <!-- 予約済みリスト -->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>時間帯</th>
            <th>予約者</th>
            <th>操作</th>
        </tr>

        <tr th:each="reservation : ${reservations}">
            <td><span th:text="${reservation.startTime}"></span> <span
                th:text="${reservation.endTime}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${reservation.user.lastName}"></span> <span
                th:text="${reservation.user.firstName}"></span></td>
            <td>
                <form th:action="@{'/reservations/' + ${date} + '/' + ${roomId}}"
                    method="post"
                    sec:authorize="${hasRole('ADMIN') or #vars.user.userId == #vars.reservation.user.userId}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="reservationId"
                        th:value="${reservation.reservationId}" /> <input type="submit"
                        name="cancel" value="取り消し" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```xml
<!-- springsecurity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

ReservationsContoroller.java

```java
package mrs.app.reservation;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import mrs.domain.model.ReservableRoom;
import mrs.domain.model.ReservableRoomId;
import mrs.domain.model.Reservation;
import mrs.domain.model.User;
import mrs.domain.service.reservation.AlreadyReservedException;
import mrs.domain.service.reservation.ReservationService;
import mrs.domain.service.reservation.UnavailableReservationException;
import mrs.domain.service.room.RoomService;
import mrs.domain.service.user.ReservationUserDetails;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("reservations/{date}/{roomId}")
public class ReservationsController {

    @Autowired
    RoomService roomService;
    @Autowired
    ReservationService reservationService;

    //予約確認・予約一覧画面
    //いわゆる確認画面だけでまだ予約は完了していない、予約可能かの確認作業はreserve()にて
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String reserveForm(@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) @PathVariable("date") LocalDate date,
            @PathVariable("roomId") Integer roomId, Model model) {

        //指定日かつ指定会議室のreservableRoomIdを生成
        ReservableRoomId reservableRoomId = new ReservableRoomId(roomId, date);

        //指定日かつ指定会議室の予約リストを取得
        List<Reservation> reservations = reservationService.findReservations(reservableRoomId);

        //LocalDateオブジェクトを作成してリストに格納する
        List<LocalTime> timeList = Stream.iterate(LocalTime.of(0, 0), t -> t.plusMinutes(30))
                .limit(24 * 2)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        model.addAttribute("room", roomService.findMeetingRomm(roomId));
        model.addAttribute("reservations", reservations);
        model.addAttribute("timeList", timeList);
        //model.addAttribute("user", dummyUser());

        return "reservation/reserveForm";

    }

    //予約処理・予約可能かの処理
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String reserve(@Validated ReservationForm form, BindingResult bindingResult,
            @AuthenticationPrincipal ReservationUserDetails userDetails,
            @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) @PathVariable("date") LocalDate date,
            @PathVariable("roomId") Integer roomId, Model model) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return reserveForm(date, roomId, model);
        }

        Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
        reservation.setStartTime(form.getStartTime());
        reservation.setEndTime(form.getEndTime());
        ReservableRoom reservableRoom = new ReservableRoom(new ReservableRoomId(roomId, date));
        reservation.setReservableRoom(reservableRoom);
        //reservation.setUser(dummyUser());
        reservation.setUser(userDetails.getUser());

        try {
            //★ここではじめてreservable_roomに登録されているか、重複していないかをチェック
            reservationService.reserve(reservation);

        } catch (UnavailableReservationException | AlreadyReservedException e) {
            model.addAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
            return reserveForm(date, roomId, model);
        }

        return "redirect:/reservations/{date}/{roomId}";
    }

    //予約削除
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "cancel")
    String cancel(@RequestParam("reservationId") Integer reservationId,
            @AuthenticationPrincipal ReservationUserDetails userDetails,
            @PathVariable("roomId") Integer roomId,
            @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) @PathVariable("date") LocalDate date, Model model) {

        //ユーザー取得
        User user = userDetails.getUser();

        try {
            reservationService.cancel(reservationId, user);

        } catch (AccessDeniedException e) { //ハンドリングする例外はAccessDeniedException
            model.addAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
            return reserveForm(date, roomId, model);
        }

        return "redirect:/reservations/{date}/{roomId}";
    }

    //予約時間のデフォルトForm
    @ModelAttribute
    ReservationForm setUpForm() {
        ReservationForm form = new ReservationForm();
        //デフォルト値
        form.setStartTime(LocalTime.of(9, 0));
        form.setEndTime(LocalTime.of(10, 0));

        return form;
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```java
package mrs;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import mrs.domain.service.user.ReservationUserDetailsService;

@Configuration

//springsecurityのweb連帯機能(CSRF対策など)を有効にする
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    ReservationUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/loginForm")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/rooms", true)
                .failureUrl("/loginForm?error=true").permitAll()
                ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //指定のUserDetailsServiceとPasswordEncoderを使用して認証を行う
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Comment: Spring Securityのバージョンは何ですか？

Comment: Maven依存関係の所で確認したところ、使用しているSpring Securityのバージョンは2.4.0となります。またSpring Bootのバージョンは2.4.0で、thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5を使用しています。

Comment: 本当ですか？`thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5`はSpring Security 5.xと連携するモジュールなので、それではうまく動作しないように思いますね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。はい、上記の物を使用しております。
mavenのjarファイルを見ると、spring-boot-starter-security-2.4.0.jarとなっています。またspring-security-coreは5.4.1となっています。

Spring Securityのバージョンを上げればいいのでしょうか？まだSpring Securityの理解が曖昧なので、どのバージョンがあっているのかわかりません..

Comment: spring-security-coreが5.4.1であれば、OKですね。うーん、ぱっと見書き方も間違っていないように見えます。`AuthorizeAttrProcessor.isVisible()`にブレークポイント設定しておくと、どのように判定しているか分かるんじゃないかと思います。

Comment: AuthorizeAttrProcessor.isVisible()にブレークポイントを設定してみました。
特に問題は出ておらず、attributeValueの値はhasRole('ADMIN') or #vars.user.userId == #vars.reservation.user.userId、hasAuthorityの場合はhasAuthority('ADMIN') or #vars.user.userId == #vars.reservation.user.userIdとなっていました。
よくわかっていませんが、一見問題のなさそうに思いました。

色々と調べた結果、#strings.contains(#authentication.principal.authorities,'ADMIN')、または#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()') and #strings.contains(#authentication.principal.authorities,'ADMIN')とするとRoleの判断が上手くいきました。

ただなぜこれらの方法だと上手くRoleを判断したのかは、理解していません。。

Answer (score 1):

質問文に記載されている情報だけでは状況を把握するのに不十分ですが、書籍 [Spring徹底入門](https://www.shoeisha.co.jp/book/detail/9784798142470) のコードをベースに作成されていると思われましたのでそれをベースに回答します。

> デバックしたところ、RoleにはきちんとADMINがセットされています。エラーメッセージなどは出ていません。

具体的にどのように確認されたのか不明確ですが、ここで検証される値は `User` の `roleName` では無いです(無関係というわけでもないですが)。

検証の対象となるのは `ReservationUserDetails#getAuthorities()` によって得られる情報で、ここには `ROLE_ADMIN` などが設定されることになります。

この情報について、次のようにコードを少し修正するとJavaから実際に設定されている値を確認することができます。

```java
    // 引数を追加: @AuthenticationPrincipal ReservationUserDetails userDetails
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String reserveForm(@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) @PathVariable("date") LocalDate date,
        @PathVariable("roomId") Integer roomId, Model model,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal ReservationUserDetails userDetails) {

        // authorities に想定した権限(ROLE_ADMIN など)が含まれるか？
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = userDetails.getAuthorities();

        // ...
    }
```

---

(コメントを受けて追記)

`ReservationUserDetails.java`内の`getAuthorities()`実装について、サンプルコードでは次のようになっています。
この部分が想定通り実装されていないのではないかと考えます。

```java
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_" + this.user.getRoleName().name());
    }
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。  
はい、書籍のSpring徹底入門を参考にさせて頂いています。
ご指摘の通り、UserのroleNameの値で検証をしていました。確かに、検証するべきはReservationUserDetails#getAuthorities()によって得られる情報だと指摘されてから気づきました。  
    
ReservationUserDetails#getAuthorities()の戻り値を確認したところ、「ROLEADMIN」となっていました(hasRole(),hasAuthority()のどちらも)。なぜ「ROLE_ADMIN」とならないのかは、調べていますがまだ不明です。 アンダーバーが無いためにRoleが判断されていないのでしょうか？　　

色々と調べた結果、#strings.contains(#authentication.principal.authorities,'ADMIN')、または#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()') and #strings.contains(#authentication.principal.authorities,'ADMIN')とするとRoleの判断が上手くいきました。

Comment: 確認したところ、ROLEにアンダーバーがついておらずgetAuthorities()が正しく実装されていませんでした。
ご指摘ありがとうございました、ユーザー認証作業の工程が理解しきれていないので、もう一度コードを読み直します。